# ¿En qué medida las cadenas compactas de Java 9 afectarán nuestras aplicaciones?

Tags: java, java-9

Una de las novedades más sonadas de Java 9 son las llamadas **cadenas compactas**, las cuales han sido creadas para *adoptar una representación interna más espaciosa para las cadenas*, [según se explica en la JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254).

También se habla de una **nueva Clase `String`**, y de que las cadenas compactas afectarán a las clases relacionadas con las cadenas, como `AbstractStringBuilder`, `StringBuilder` y `StringBuffer`.

Esta es la descripción de la JEP 254 (el enlace es el mismo de más arriba):

> Proponemos cambiar la representación interna de la clase String de una
>   matriz de caracteres `UTF-16` a una matriz de bytes más un campo de
>   encoding-flag. **La nueva clase `String`** almacenará caracteres
>   codificados como `ISO-8859-1 / Latin-1` (un byte por carácter), o como
>   `UTF-16` (dos bytes por carácter), basado en el contenido de la
>   cadena. El indicador de codificación indicará qué codificación se
>   utiliza.
>
> Las clases relacionadas con cadenas como `AbstractStringBuilder`,
>   `StringBuilder` y `StringBuffer` se actualizarán para utilizar la
>   misma representación, al igual que las operaciones de cadena
>   intrínseca de la HotSpot VM.
>
> Esto es puramente un cambio de implementación, sin cambios en las
>   interfaces públicas existentes. No hay planes para agregar nuevas API
>   públicas u otras interfaces.

El último párrafo de este texto no me queda claro y por lo que me pregunto en qué medida afectarán las cadenas compactas nuestras aplicaciones ya creadas o las aplicaciones que creemos a partir de Java 9.

Comment: Yo lo que entiendo es que sera transparente para los usuarios y solo afectara al codigo interno de dichas Clases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En... ¡nada! Bueno, con suerte quizás consuman algo menos de memoria.

Se trata de un cambio interno a OpenJDK de un detalle de implementación, el estándar Java no cambia para nada.

De la página web, objetivos del cambio:

> Improve the space efficiency of the String class and related classes while maintaining performance in most scenarios and preserving full compatibility for all related Java and native interfaces.

Ningún cambio de comportamiento, sólo hacer que consuman menos espacio de memoria.

Del apartado de testing:

> Thorough compatibility and regression testing will be essential for a change to such a fundamental part of the platform.

O lo que es lo mismo, asegurarse de que el cambio no afecte al comportamiento de las clases más allá de la mejora de memoria.

Comment: Coincido contigo. Sobretodo en la primera oración: "con suerte quizás consuman algo menos de memoria." Lo peor que puede pasar es que sea un efecto rebote y se vuelvan más pesadas o que decremente el rendimiento por tratar de adivinar el encoding a usar para la cadena.

Comment: Entonces si lo del _con suerte_ no es simple especulación ¿podrían tener un impacto negativo según lo que afirmas @Luiggi-Mendoza? ¿Podrías justificar esa afirmación?

Comment: @A.Cedano todo dependerá de la JVM a usar. Ahora que tenemos por lo menos 3 JVMs que aplican para Java 9: OpenJDK, J9 y HotSpot, lo mejor será evaluar aquella que impacte menos. Pero por lo que estoy viendo ahora, el problema de compactar las cadenas es mucho menor comparado al sistema de módulos.

Comment: @A.Cedano según [este video, en el minuto 1:42:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1061&v=CkmB86pCV6A) (aproximadamente), explican que un efecto de Java 9 es que el valor interno de las cadenas deja de ser `char[]` y ahora es `byte[]`. Esto significa que, si por alguna muy extraña razón, usas reflection en una cadena para obtener el `char[] value` dentro de tu código, esto generará un error de compilación/ejecución con Java 9. Un caso extremo pero puede suceder.